# Adding Object with Transition in D3.js after Zooming

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

In the d3.js example, the goal is to change the X & Y scales to reveal a newly added circle which is added offscreen.

[image]

Currently, if you were to change the zoom scale, then click on the button to add a new circle, the zoom level suddenly resets to 1. Now dragging the view will cause the zoom scale to become correct again, which is the same zoom scale right before adding the circle.

However this problem goes away if you change `redrawWithTransition()` on line 123 to `redraw()` which removes the transitions.

Everything works fine if you add the circle without first zooming.

Why do we have to drag the view again to get the correct zoom scale back? How can we avoid having to do this additional drag and still use transitions in `redrawWithTransition()`? Thank you!!

**Jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/NgWmU/

---

Because panning again after adding the circle solves the problem, I tried calling `redraw()` at the end but theres no difference! Is the panning/zooming triggering something else in addition to `redraw()`?

**Jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/NgWmU/2/

---

First the user zooms/pans around and ends up with a view like in figure A. Next the new circle is added and we should get figure C, but instead we get figure B where the user's current translate/zoom is changed significantly.

[image]

---

### Another case

If the user pan/zoom to a view similar to the top figure, adding the new circle should reposition the existing circles slightly, but instead the entire view is reset.

[image]

Was thinking about something like:

```
// Copy existing domains
var xMinOld = xMin,
    xMaxOld = xMax,
    yMinOld = yMin,
    yMaxOld = yMax;

// Update domains
var yMin = d3.min(data.map( function(d) { return d; } )),
    yMax = d3.max(data.map( function(d) { return d; } )),
    xMin = d3.min(data.map( function(d) { return d; } )),
    xMax = d3.max(data.map( function(d) { return d; } ));

if(x.domain()[0] > newData[0] || x.domain()[1] < newData[0]) {
    if(x.domain()[0] > newData[0]) {
        x.domain([xMin, xMaxOld]);
    } else {
        x.domain([xMinOld, xMax]);
    }
    zoom.x(x);
}

if(y.domain()[0] > newData[0] || y.domain()[1] < newData[0]) {
    if(y.domain()[0] > newData[0]) {
        y.domain([yMin, yMaxOld]);
    } else {
        y.domain([yMinOld, yMax]);
    }
    zoom.y(y);
}
```

But eventually the view will still be reset because we pass the updated scales `x` and `y` into `zoom`...

Comment: It looks like you're resetting the translation after adding the circle. Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NgWmU/3/) what you're looking for?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I'll like the zoom/translate to remain almost the same (and not be reset) after adding the new circle. Otherwise a user who has panned/zoomed to a spot will keep getting his pan/zoom reset whenever the dataset updates every minute.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for then. Don't you want to zoom such that the new node is shown?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Yes the new node should be shown, but the user's view should not be changed drastically. Updated the post with a few figures.

Comment: So all you need to do is check whether the current zoom/translate would show the circle?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Sounds like it. I guess the logic will be: If current zoom/translate will show the circle, then just add the circle. If currrent zoom/translate will not show the new circle, add the new circle and change(tween) the zoom/translate to show the new circle so the new circle kind of slides in from offscreen.

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/NgWmU/4/)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Wow almost! I posted an example of a case in the original post where it didn't quite work...

Comment: Not sure if I understand. The idea is to only update the domains if you have to to show the circle. In what case would this not work?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff If the view is zoomed out before adding the new circle and translated to force the new circle to appear offscreen (illustrated in latest post update), updating all 4 values that define the domain will cause the view to kind of reset. I am thinking only updating 1 domain value for x scale (xMin or xMax) and 1 domain value for y scale (yMin or yMax). But after updating the scales `x` and `y` with the new domains, we still have to pass them into `zoom`, which will cause the translate/zoom to reset... Sorry if I dont make sense

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. The code you've posted in your last update should take care of that though, no? You would only update in the direction that you need to.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff http://jsfiddle.net/NgWmU/5/ I think it does, just that passing the scales `x` and `y` back into `zoom` causes the view to reset again.

Comment: In this case you do actually need to set translate/zoom again -- http://jsfiddle.net/NgWmU/6/